# Can ArrayInput save key: 'value'?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-admin

I am using `react-admin` framework and I need to save my data to an attribute `options[]` like this:

[image]

First thing that came to my mind was `ArrayInput`, but I came accross this problem. ArrayInput saves the data in this format, which is not what I need.

[image]

Any suggestions how can I modify `ArrayInput` so it will save the data as it is in the first image? Is it even possible? Or should I make custom component for this?

My code so far:

```
<ArrayInput source="options">
   <SimpleFormIterator>
      <TextInput source='options' />
   </SimpleFormIterator>
</ArrayInput>
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily extend your data provider based on the example:
"Extending a Data Provider (Example of File Upload)" and then inside the extension to convert your data to any format:

https://marmelab.com/react-admin/DataProviders.html